# Placing 4 divs around each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put 4 div next to the each other like this:

```
 __  __  __
|  ||__||  |
|  | __ |  |
|__||__||__|
```

this is How i'm trying to do this:

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
  background:rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 100px;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.top{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.right{
  display: inline;
  width: 20px;
  height: 110px;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left{
  display: inline;
  width: 20px;
  height: 110px;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bot{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
        <div class="main">
        
                <div class="left" >
                      <p>left</p>
                </div>
        
                <div class="top">
                      <p>top</p>
                </div>
        
                <div class="bot" >
                      <p>bot</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="right" >
                      <p>right</p>
                </div>
        
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But as you can see they just show up next to each other. I'm a little bit confused with `display:` here. I would appreciate a little help on How to show them like the pattern above                                                 .

Comment: http://learnlayout.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways of doing this, but given you've start using flex, I'd focus on that.

[This is a great link for understanding flex.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Your `main` container  is the flex parent in your snippet, all the other divs are children. `main` has the default `flex-direction` of `row`, i.e. it lays outfrom left to right.

The minimal change to add the vertical stack is to wrap `top` and `bot` in a new flex parent, and give that div `flex-direction` of `column`, i.e. layout top to bottom.

I'd look up a few flex layout tutorials. I haven't looked too hard but you should then be able to drop some of the existing CSS.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 100px;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.right {
  display: inline;
  width: 20px;
  height: 110px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left {
  display: inline;
  width: 20px;
  height: 110px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div class="main">

    <div class="left">
      <p>left</p>
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
      <div class="top">
        <p>top</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bot">
        <p>bot</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <p>right</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a container to the middle, you should be good to go.

```
<html>
<body>
        <div class="main">

                <div class="left" >
                      <p>left</p>
                </div>
                <div class="mid" >
                  <div class="top">
                        <p>top</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="bot" >
                        <p>bot</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right" >
                      <p>right</p>
                </div>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0oLqx6dh/